# what is the command to determine the title of the most expensive book published by Pocket Books?

Tags: mysql

here my tables. What is the query to determine the title of the most expensive book published by Pocket Books?

[image]

[image]

Comment: `SELECT book_title FROM book WHERE publisher_code = 'PB' ORDER BY book_price DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: And why redact every other instance of 'dequina'

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT b.BOOK_TITLE,b.BOOK_PRICE 
FROM book b inner join publisher p on b.PUBLISHER_CODE = p.PUBLISHER_CODE
WHERE p.PUBLISHER_NAME = 'Pocket Books' ORDER BY BOOK_PRICE DESC LIMIT 1
```